# Can I delete all migration files and start from scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rails-api

I have a Rails-API app that I'm going to re-deploy after a long time. The app is non-production, but I am ready to deploy the production version. I want to basically delete all the migration files and start from scratch using the schema, is there any problem with this approach? Assuming I can do this, what do I need to alter the schema.rb to? Is this a common practice? Seems reasonable to me.

```
# what do I change the version param value to?
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171129023538)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations are used to update your database or to rollback to previous versions. Once migrations have been run in all environments, they're never looked at again (unless you're manually messing around with the `schema_migrations` table of course). Once all your migrations have been run, the current state of the database is in `db/schema.rb` (or `db/structure.sql`) so `schema.rb` is all you need to start with a fresh database.

I tend to clear out old migrations every couple months just to cut down on clutter.

As far as the version goes, you can leave it alone. As long as it represent a time in the past (such as 2017-11-29 02:35:38) and it is lower than any migrations that need to be run (which doesn't apply as you're deleting them all) then it doesn't matter what it is.

Go ahead and clear out all the migrations, they're already reflected in `schema.rb` and you can always dig them out of revision control if you really need them.

Comment: and what of ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171129023538) once I delete all my migration files? version: 0? Or does it matter, as any migrations after that will replace that value?

Comment: Just leave it alone, 2017-11-29 02:35:38 is in the past and you won't have any migrations left so it is fine as-is.

Comment: Worked. Cool beans.

Comment: MIght want to add that to your answer, as that was part of my question!

Comment: I thought the third paragraph covered that, sorry if it wasn't as clear as it could have been.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to keep old migrations. As per Rails own schema.rb file (in the comments), the DB should be recreated from the schema.rb and not from migrations.

You can clean out old migrations with a Rake task like this:

```rb
# lib/tasks/migration_archive.rake
namespace :db do
  namespace :migrate do
    desc 'Archives old DB migration files'
    task :archive do
      sh 'mkdir -p db/migrate/archive'
      sh '[ ! -f src ] || mv db/migrate/*.rb db/migrate/archive'
    end
  end
end
```

Source: https://codewithrails.com/clean-up-db-migrations